# Record Get method does not seem to work

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am retrieving a record from my grid like so.

```
var record = myGrid.store.getAt(j);
```

When I look at the field in **record.data** I get a string value :

```
console('record.data ' + record.data['groupSelected']) //something!!
```

However when I use the **record.get** method I get undefined.

```
console('record.get[groupSelected] ' + record.get['groupSelected']) //nothing!!
```

Am I using the record object correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong type of brackets.

```
console('record.get(groupSelected) ' + record.get('groupSelected')) //nothing!!
```

should do the trick.